# Setting folder icon in Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: macos, mac

I would like to set a folder icon in Mac OS X 10.6.

I found an Apple KB that mentioned you use "get info", then double click the folders icon and paste in an image but that didn't work with a png file.

Any suggestions?

Will that work if the folder is also a stackable in the dock?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be made into a proper icon first, that's probably why it didn't work. I'd check out this tutorial on [How To Create Icons for Mac OS X](http://tutorialdog.com/how-to-create-icons-for-mac-os-x/).

To change an item's icon to another one:

> 1. Select the volume, application, folder, or file whose icon you want to
>      stamp onto another, just click the
>      icon to select it.
> 2. From the **File** menu, choose **Get Info** or press Command-I to open the Info
>      window.
> 3. Click the icon in the upper-left corner of the Info window to select
>      it.
> 4. From the **Edit** menu, choose **Copy** or press Command-C.
> 5. Select the volume, application, folder, or file whose icon you want to
>      replace.
> 6. From the **File** menu, choose **Get Info** or press Command-I.
> 7. Click the icon in the upper-left corner.
> 8. From the **Edit** menu, choose **Paste** or press Command-V to replace the icon.

[Mac 101: Change your icons](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2493)

Comment: what about if the folder is stack in the dock?

Comment: It depends on the folder's name as the stack sorts alphabetically I believe. The stack's icon is chosen by whichever application is sorted at the top of the stack. If you want a folder to sort near the top of a stack, start it's name with a 0 (zero).

Comment: Folders in the dock will show custom icons after you log out, or you can drag the folder out of the dock and then drag it back in and it will update with your custom icon.

Comment: You can also right-click on the item in the stack and choose *Display As... > Folder* instead of *Stack*.

Answer (score 1):

The above but use .gif files if you can I have found that these are better. .png files dont work for me and .jpg files seems to have a back ground.

Comment: Or: use Preview as the intermediate. First open an image file, or paste any format, into Preview. Next, copy from Preview. Finally, paste into the Get Info window.